# How to play a few video in youtube player on Java, Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a few videos for Android. My app plays it by code:

```
Intent youtube=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
startActivityForResult(youtube, 100);
```

But it code play 1 video from list. How can I put a few video for Intent in order to standart player play it in series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playlists are not supported. You will have to write your own,

- create a list of videos
- Lauch the new activity using `startActivityForResult`
- In the `onActivityResult` just launch the same activity with the new video file.